# Jquery Slider with images of different sizes

Tags: jquery

1. I need to build an image slider with images of different heights.
2. I don't want any gaps between images. If any image is small, it should show up with an appropriate padding or margin.
3. Image slider should not be wrap.

Comment: can you please explain it more clearly,as i don't understand your requirement properly. Which plugin you are using? Your slider is in vertical or in horizontal?

Comment: i  am  using  vertical  slider..  and  i  want  to  use  different  size of  images(different height with same width).                                                                         my  problem is  that  when  i  used  different images  with different height  my  slider wrap  according to   big  images and  small images have  space according  to big  images.

Answer (score 0):

For smaller images, you can try something like this:

```
var imageWidth = $('#image').outerWidth();
var margin = (120 - imageWidth) / 2; //120 is your slider's width here

$('#image').css({
    marginLeft: margin,
    marginRight: margin
});
```

For larger images:
Scale the images dynamically using JS by applying width only. Say your slider is 120px wide, apply image width as 120, and no height. That will allow the images to adjust automatically preserving the aspect ratio.

```
$('#image').css('width', '120px');
```